# Woocommerce use child them 'inc' folder

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize my woo-commerce site but don't want to change parent (orignal) theme. So i have created a child theme and all works fine. Now i want to change `woocommerce.php` in inc folder. I have created inc folder in child theme but still its loading files from parent theme inc folder.

What should be the possible solutions to use child theme inc folder?? Also few of things can not be done via child theme functions.php so its must to use inc folder of child theme.

Comment: Is `woocommerce.php` a template file? I don't see it in WooCommerce core so my guess is no. If not, it won't follow the template override system.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but i think you need to have *woocommerce.php* in root child theme directory and not in an **inc** subfolder.